# How can I update data from a dynamically changing table with a method using C# and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to write a function that takes the table name as a parameter and updates the related data items `isActive` and `isUpdated` attributes using Entity Framework.

Here's what I've tried:

```
public void FuncDelete(string tableName)
{
    // Getting data id value from a text box:
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(IDBox);

    // Trying to get the column on the related id value:
    var TBL_Name = db.tableName.Find(x);

    // Changing the attributes:
    TBL_Name.isActive = false;
    TBL_Name.isUpdated = true;
    db.SaveChanges();
}

FuncDelete(Employee);
```

Obviously this doesn't work. I'm new to C# and Entity Framework. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: EF deals with application entities, not tables,  it's not a database driver or query builder. EF is an ORM - it Maps application Objects to relational constructs, trying to give programmers the impression of working with application objects, not tables. There's no reason for the table to change if the application class doesn't change

Comment: Besides, what you posted isn't a DELETE, it's a "soft delete", a [hacky way of emulating actual business requirements](https://ayende.com/blog/4157/avoid-soft-deletes) like maintaining history. It's hacky because *no* business process works that way, history isn't really maintained and worse, integrity is compromised by the inevitable duplications and semi-inactive object graphs. In databases with temporal tables like SQL Server, a *far* better option would be to use temporal tables and real deletes. Real business processes don't use soft deletes either, they use cancellation or compensations

Comment: The correct way to implement auditing or "soft deletes" is with [Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors). A SaveChanges interceptor can convert DELETE operations to attribute changes and update auditing columns while [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) can ensure "inactive" rows aren't loaded. That doesn't solve the problem of "active" related entities that refer to "inactive" parent rows.

Answer (score 0):

The comments by Panagiotis are valid, but the answer given here may also be helpful in other circumstances so here goes...

I am assuming that you have entity classes for each of the tables that you wish to access. I am also assuming that you're using .NET core, which makes things a little more tricky as you no longer have a plain DbSet object like you did in EF6, only DbSet<T>. But if you really want to, you can still achieve what you want using reflection:

```
public void FuncDelete(string tableName, int id)
{
    // Get the entity name from the table name - it could be different!
    var entityName = db.Model.GetEntityTypes().FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetTableName() == tableName);
    // Get the generic DbSet
    var dbSet = typeof(MyDbContext)
        .GetMethod("Set", 1, Type.EmptyTypes)
        .MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(entityName.Name))
        .Invoke(db, null);
    // Find the record with the specified id
    var record = dbSet.GetType()
        .GetMethod("Find")
        .Invoke(dbSet, new object[] { new object[] { id } });
    // Set the flags
    record.GetType()
        .GetProperty("isActive")
        .SetValue(record, false);
    record.GetType()
        .GetProperty("isUpdated")
        .SetValue(record, true);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

It sure ain't pretty though...

Answer (score -2):

You can always use generics:

```
public async Task FuncDelete<T>() where T : class
{
  int x = Convert.ToInt32(IDBox);
  var queryStream = db.Set<T>.AsQueryable();
  var o = await queryStream.Where(w => w.Id == x).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
  o.IsActive = false;
  o.IsUpdated = true;
  db.Entry(o).State = EntityState.Modified;
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Then call it:

```
FuncDelete<Employee>();
```

Comment: You can't use _any_ type `T` with EF: you can only use classes that have been specifically configured with the `DbContext` with `DbContext.Set<T>()`, furthermore, those types are still going to be _statically defined_, rather than runtime-dynamic - so this doesn't help the OP at all.

Comment: @Dai would where T : class satisfy you? I'm doing the same thing as the OP and it works for me!

Comment: Try it with  `FuncDelete<String>` and tell me what happens - or `FuncDelete<SqlConnection>` et cetera - it isn't as simple as you're making it out to be.

Comment: @Dai Then how would you solve the problem?

Comment: The OP's problem is impossible to solve. EF doesn't support "dynamic tables". It's that simple.

Comment: It depends - if we're dealing with a fixed set of tables that the OP has scaffolded, then it is very possible. But otherwise - no.

Comment: I feel bad for the OPs on this site.

Comment: That's too cheap. Please, don't flee from your responsibility to post good answers. Face it, this would only work if the generic type constraint could be an interface or an abstract class implemented by all classes that implement soft delete.